# Sort the column (by time) from smallest to the largest

Tags: r, sorting, time, time-series, timestamp

I have this dataframe (in 1-min frequency) where the columns represent the timestamps. I want to sort these columns from early time to later time (e.g., from 00:00 to 23:59). Now it starts with 06:43 till 06:42.

```
    > head(data3)
# A tibble: 6 × 1,440
  `06:43` `06:44` `06:45` `06:46` `06:47` `06:48` `06:49` `06:50` `06:51` `06:52`
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 3       2       2       3       3       2       1       0       1       1      
2 7       6       6       6       6       6       6       5       5       6      
3 10      9       9       7       5       3       M       M       M       M      
4 M       M       M       M       M       M       M       M       M       M
```

At first, for the list of small columns names, I think of this usual way

```
col_order <- c("00:00", "00:01", ..., "23:59") # write down all columns
data3 <- data3[, col_order]
data3
```

But obviously, it is too much to write down all the col names there (1440 columns) and it seems 'silly'.

Is there anyway to do it in R? Kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @Onyambu it is not sorted yet, I want the order from 00:00 to 23:59 but now it starts with 6:43, 6:44, ...., 00:00, 00:01, 00:02, ...., 23:59, ...., 6:41, 6:42

Comment: did you try the code i gave?

Comment: @Onyambu it does not make any change yet...

Comment: @sehne it doesnt make change to the original table. store it in a new variable

Comment: Your data _here_ progresses from `06:43` through `06:52`, there is no `06:42` in this data. However, perhaps `df[sort(names(df))]` would work. If not, please (a) [edit] your question to include data that is more representative of the problem; and (b) show what code you have tried and why it does not work. When updating data, it is often preferred to include the output from `dput(head(data3))` instead of the console output, as it provides an unambiguous dataset without us needing to parse and adjust (if necessary). Thanks!

Comment: If your data has `6:42` instead (no leading `0`), then ... of course it will sort out of sequence, since `12:` will always sort before `6:` (_alphabetically_), though it should have ended on `9:`-something instead of `6:`-something.

Comment: @ScottHunter I edited it as there.

Comment: @r2evans I just copied the head(data3), there is 1440 columns so that was why you only saw till 06:52. Anyway, I use your command just now and it works as I expected. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is reproducible data:

```r
df <- structure(list("06:43" = c("3", "7", "10", "M"), "06:44" = c("2", "6", "9", "M"), "12:45" = c("2", "6", "9", "M"), "06:46" = c("3", "6", "7", "M"), "06:47" = c("3", "6", "5", "M"), "06:48" = c("2", "6", "3", "M"), "06:49" = c("1", "6", "M", "M"), "06:50" = c("0", "5", "M", "M"), "06:51" = c("1", "5", "M", "M"), "06:42" = c("1", "6", "M", "M")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
df
#   06:43 06:44 12:45 06:46 06:47 06:48 06:49 06:50 06:51 06:42
# 1     3     2     2     3     3     2     1     0     1     1
# 2     7     6     6     6     6     6     6     5     5     6
# 3    10     9     9     7     5     3     M     M     M     M
# 4     M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M
```

From here, sorting the column names is direct:

```r
df[,sort(names(df))]
#   06:42 06:43 06:44 06:46 06:47 06:48 06:49 06:50 06:51 12:45
# 1     1     3     2     3     3     2     1     0     1     2
# 2     6     7     6     6     6     6     6     5     5     6
# 3     M    10     9     7     5     3     M     M     M     9
# 4     M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M
```

Note that if, per your comments, you have a column named `"6:42"` with no leading zero, then this will break alphabetic sorting. In that case, then perhaps:

```r
names(df)[10] <- "6:42" # just to show it, don't do this
df[,order(as.numeric(sub(":", ".", names(df))))]
#   6:42 06:43 06:44 06:46 06:47 06:48 06:49 06:50 06:51 12:45
# 1    1     3     2     3     3     2     1     0     1     2
# 2    6     7     6     6     6     6     6     5     5     6
# 3    M    10     9     7     5     3     M     M     M     9
# 4    M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M
```

Comment: In case 2: We could use `mixedsort` `install.packages("gtools")
library(gtools)
df_sorted <- df[, gtools::mixedsort(names(df))]`

Answer (score 0):

We can `sub` away the colon and coerce `as.integer` which is robust against the discussed typos without leading zero.

```
> df[order(as.integer(sub(':', '', names(df))))]
  06:42 06:43 6:44 06:46 06:47 06:48 06:49 06:50 06:51 12:45
1     1     3    2     3     3     2     1     0     1     2
2     6     7    6     6     6     6     6     5     5     6
3     M    10    9     7     5     3     M     M     M     9
4     M     M    M     M     M     M     M     M     M     M
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(`06:43` = c("3", "7", "10", "M"), `6:44` = c("2", 
"6", "9", "M"), `12:45` = c("2", "6", "9", "M"), `06:46` = c("3", 
"6", "7", "M"), `06:47` = c("3", "6", "5", "M"), `06:48` = c("2", 
"6", "3", "M"), `06:49` = c("1", "6", "M", "M"), `06:50` = c("0", 
"5", "M", "M"), `06:51` = c("1", "5", "M", "M"), `06:42` = c("1", 
"6", "M", "M")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
```